# Customising the header image and background colour in Apple App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I came across a few apps that have a customised App Store presence – [OkCupid](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/okcupid-dating/id338701294?mt=8), [Badoo](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/badoo-meet-new-people-chat/id351331194?mt=8), [POF](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/pof-free-dating-app/id389638243?mt=8), plus a whole lot more.
These include a custom header image and custom background colour with a gradient in between.

How can we add these for our apps?

Example screenshots:

[image: App Store iPhone][image: App Store iPad]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can change check below link:

http://thenextweb.com/dd/2013/10/29/get-featured-app-store/

Comment: Why did you say "Yes, you can change"? No, you can't, unless Apple features your app!