# For some apps there is a icon shown on top of Appstore Metadata, How can we edit it?

Tags: ios, image, app-store

[image]For some apps there is an app icon at top of the iTunes description and some apps it doesn't . How can we configure that?

[image]

Comment: Which icon do you mean? The big skype icon? It should be present for all apps.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749972/customize-apps-gallery-in-appstore-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the **"Essentials" badge**, these are hand-picked apps by the App Store team. There is **no way** for you as a developer or publisher to configure it in iTunes Connect.

Same goes for the header image and background color Timur mentioned in the comments.

Comment: In the screenshot you can see flipcart has a logo on the top and Skype doesn't have it. In iTunes I didn't see any option to configure that logo for my application. How can we configure that?

Comment: I can just repeat myself and the comment Timur made: All customization of the app store pages is made by the App Store team, you cannot customize anything. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936244/customising-the-header-image-and-background-colour-in-apple-app-store